# How to write post response in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to convert this php code in to laravel?
While add this code in laravel blade getting error?

```
 <?php
 $status=$_POST["status"];
 echo "<h3>Thank You. Your order status is ". $status .".</h3>";         
 ?>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? This needs to be part of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is an MVC framework, so the business logic remains in controller function like:

```
$status = Input::get('status');
```

and pass it to view like:

```
return view('view_name', ['status' => $status]);
```

and you can use this variable on view like:

```
<h3>Thank You. Your order status is {{ $status }}</h3>
```